# Restart a systemd service (B), if another service (A) restarts, but only if service (B) was started

Tags: systemd

I have a standard systemd service (A = gpsd.service) running at startup.

I have a custom systemd service (B = my_gps_logger.service) which is not enabled by default, so that a user has to manually start it (for diagnosis).  The logger service is a bash script with `gpscat /dev/ttyPS1 > my_log.log`

If I restart gpsd, it fails because my logger service has the device open.

I worked around that by using `BindsTo=gpsd.service` in my logger service.

So now if I restart gpsd, my logger service stops and gpsd restarts ok.

HOWEVER, it does not restart my logger service !!

I don't know if `PartOf=` is the answer.  It feels wrong (and my tests show it didn't restart the logger).

But I don't want to restart my logger service anytime gpsd is started.  Only if the logger service was running and was stopped/restarted because gpsd was restarted.  If the logger service wasn't running, then I don't want it to autmomatically start up.

Any ideas how I can configure systemd services to achieve this?